# Firefox Bug since Version 18

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, firefox, richfaces

I am using Java Server Faces, JQuery and JavaScript. I think I detected a bug in Firefox.
This JavaScript code gets triggered:

```
var list = jQuery('input.myclass');
var item = list.eq(0);
item.click();
top.location.reload(true);
```

The click will hit an a4j:commandButton which is related to my action-method 'mybean.myaction()'. If I am using Firefox 19 or Firefox 18 maybe the button get clicked. Anyway, the reload of the page happens too fast. I can see this by setting an Eclipse-breakpoint in mybean.myaction() - the breakpoint never got reached.

If I am using Firefox 17, InternetExplorer all works like expected, the Javascript got triggered, the click happens, the bean-method adjusts the state of the bean and the page got reloaded.

Thanks in advance for giving me some ideas how to clarify the reason for this behaviour. If appropriate I will file a bug in Firefox bugzilla.

UPDATE: this is the a4j:commandButton which gets clicked by JQuery;

```
<a4j:commandButton action="#{mybean.myaction}" value="setMyVal" styleClass="hidden myclass">
    <a4j:actionparam name="myparamname" value="MY_VAL" assignTo="#{mybean.myattr}" /></a4j:commandButton>
```

UPDATE-2: I played around to isolate the problem. I placed a try-catch-statement around the block and moreover I replaced the reload() that I will be able to follow the javascript-execution. Now, I can see that if I enter top.location.host I will jump to the catch-block, but my errorText is 'undefinded'. How can this happen? What do I have to do, to find out more of this exception?

```
try{ ...
    item.click();
    // Firefox-Bug in Version ab 18.0.1
    var res = top.location.host; //top.location.reload(true);
} catch (e) {
    var errorText = e.message; // errorText is undefined! 
    alert("Exception: " + errorText);
}
```

UPDATE-3: it gets stranger and stranger ... if I set a Firebug-Breakpoint between item.click() and top.location.reload(true); all went fine! Due to this, maybe the problem is the a4j. Maybe it is wise to quit for today. Thanks for all your help up to now!

Comment: The given code looks fine. I think the event handler has some asynchronous behaviour wich causes your problems. Can you show us what happens when item is clicked?

Comment: It seems you're using Richfaces here. It comes with its own embedded version of jQuery. What version of Richfaces are you using?

Comment: I am using RichFaces 3.3.x, for sure that is quite old, but JQuery.click() should work (and works fine in all other areas of our app). I think the problem is that the reload of the page happens too early. Moreover I cannot see a Javascript error in my Firebug console.

Comment: You could make a public testcase and then test and compare it on http://browsershots.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not quite an answer to the question, but a suggestion on how to solve the problem. So, you can reload your page after the action is completed using the oncomplete attribute of the commandButton:

```
<a4j:commandButton action="#{mybean.myaction}" value="setMyVal" styleClass="hidden myclass" oncomplete="top.location.reload(true);">
    <a4j:actionparam name="myparamname" value="MY_VAL" assignTo="#{mybean.myattr}" />   
</a4j:commandButton>
```

This way you serialize the events: first the action is called and only after the page is reloaded. Of course you need to remove `top.location.reload(true);` from your javascript code.

**EDIT:** Thinking more to the problem... and it doesn't seem to me to be a bug. Firefox is not required anywhere to wait until your click event (a complex operation in case of Richfaces) is processed on the server. It dispatch the click event to Richfaces javascript and moves on to the next statement: `top.location.reload(true);`. You need to prevent this problem.

Comment: After my last tests to isolate the problem (update-2) I suspect that top.location is the reason for the problem.